# отправка SIP INVITE через UDP

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, sip

Нужно отправить SIP INVITE на сервер используя UDP. код:

```
import socket

R_IP = 'server_ip'
R_PORT = 5060

proto = socket.getprotobyname('udp')
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, proto)
...далее отправка сообщения
```

получаю ошибку:

> OSError: [WinError 10043] The requested protocol has not been configured into the system, or no implementation for it exists`

в чем может быть проблема? с `proto = socket.getprotobyname('tcp')` все проходит успешно